# WPF Window : sizechanged event fires twice

Tags: wpf, window

I have a WPF Window loaded. But on event of sizeChanged, it fires twice. May I know why?
Also, I have tried adding 'e.handled = true'

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, I've noticed the same thing.  If you look at the value for `e.NewSize` you'll see they are different values, with the final time being the correct size.  It must be something in the way it gets laid out.